# Binding array of string to DropDownList?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

A question that I have never solved. I will illustrate with two code samples in which one works and the other doesn't:

```
Page_Load()
{
        FontFamily[] oFamilyFontList = FontFamily.Families;
        DropDownList_Fonts.DataSource = oFamilyFontList;
        DropDownList_Fonts.DataBind();

        string[] colorName = System.Enum.GetNames(typeof(KnownColor));
        DropDownList_FontColor.DataSource = colorName;
        DropDownList_FontColor.DataBind();
}
```

```
    <asp:DropDownList 
        ID="DropDownList_Fonts" DataTextField="Name" 
        DataValueField="Name" runat="server" >
    </asp:DropDownList>

    <asp:DropDownList 
        ID="DropDownList_FontColor"  DataTextField="colorName" 
        DataValueField="colorName" runat="server" >
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

The first DropDownList populates fine without any errors because each object oFamilyFontList has a property 'Name' which binds with the DataText and DataValue fields.

The second one has no properties at all and it's just an array of strings. What possibly can I put inside both fields to make it work ?

Comment: Maybe a stupid question - but - are there any values in colorName array?

Comment: Ofcourse there is, AVD have answered my question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can bind an array but you have to remove `DataTextField` and `DataValueField` attributes

```
<asp:DropDownList 
        ID="DropDownList_FontColor"
        runat="server">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: i really feel stupid. Thank you very much for the answer, it worked.

Comment: @yahyakh - There is nothing stupid in it. You should never hesitate to ask for help when it's clearly needed.