# Adding text from textbox to listbox in asp.net web form

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, listbox

Ok, so I know this works on windows based forms because I have used it numerous times.....

```
        lstBoxExternal.Items.AddRange(txtBoxNameExternal.Text.Split(vbNewLine))
```

But this does not work for we based forms I am guessing? Can anyone tell me why and what the correct way to add text to a list box from a textbox on button click?

**Error**

**Value type of String cannot be converted to 1-dimensional array of System.Web.UI.WebControls.Listitem**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ASP.NET `ListBox` web control's `AddRange()` method expects an array of `ListItem` which is why it can't so easily be converted from Windows forms.

If you are using the data from the `txtBoxNameExternal` to completely replace whatever items may already be in the `ListBox` (as opposed to adding to the items) you can use `DataBind()` which is probably easiest method:

```
    lstBoxExternal.DataSource = txtBoxNameExternal.Text.Split(vbNewLine)
    lstBoxExternal.DataBind()
```

If you need to keep adding items on each button click there are a few ways you could do this but I usually do it by adding items in a loop:

```
Dim items As [String]() = txtBoxNameExternal.Text.Split(vbNewLine)
For Each item As [String] In items
    lstBoxExternal.Items.Add(New ListItem(item))
Next
```

Also see this related answer for some tips when binding string arrays to DropDownList/ListBox controls: [Binding array of string to DropDownList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8412774/binding-array-of-string-to-dropdownlist)